# Email sending with SendGrid using WebJobs

Tags: c#, azure, sendgrid, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobs-continuous

I'm trying to integrate SendGrid to a .Net 4.5 application using WebJobs.

I made the basic configurations required to send a basic email. I'm trying to run and test it in my local machine. I can't figure out how to push messages to the queue. I can't upgrade the .Net version of the application as of now. If it is possible to do this without using webjobs that is also fine.

Program.cs

```
static void Main()
{

    var config = new JobHostConfiguration();
    config.UseTimers();
    config.Queues.MaxDequeueCount = 2;
    config.Queues.MaxPollingInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4);
    config.Queues.BatchSize = 2;

    if (config.IsDevelopment)
    {
        config.UseDevelopmentSettings();
    }

    config.UseSendGrid();

    var host = new JobHost(config);
    host.RunAndBlock();
}
```

Functions.cs

```
public static void ProcessQueueMessage([QueueTrigger("queue")] string message, TextWriter log, [SendGrid(From = "no-reply@company.com", To = "employee@company.com")] out Mail mail)
{
    log.WriteLine(message);

    mail = new Mail();

    var personalization = new Personalization();
    personalization.AddBcc(new Email("employee@company.com"));

    mail.AddPersonalization(personalization);
    mail.Subject = "Test Email Subject";
    mail.AddContent(new Content("text/html", $"The message '{message}' was successfully processed."));
}
```

Found the following functions:
SendGrid_Test_002.Functions.ProcessQueueMessage
ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit is set to the default value of 2. This can limit the connection throughput to services like Azure Storage. For more information, see https://aka.ms/webjobs-connections.
Job host started

I get this on the console.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: what is the question here

Comment: I wanted to figure out why it was not working when I run it locally. There was no error also. I think I found what the issue is. I was not actually pushing any messages to the queue.

Comment: ok cool, close the question

Comment: @MadushanAmarasinghem, glad to hear that. Please write down your solution as reply to close this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to feed the messages into the webjob queue using the following code.

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

// Create the queue client.
CloudQueueClient queueClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudQueueClient();

// Retrieve a reference to a container.
CloudQueue queue = queueClient.GetQueueReference("email-queue-name");

// Create the queue if it doesn't already exist
queue.CreateIfNotExists();

// Create message to be sent to the queue
CloudQueueMessage message = new CloudQueueMessage(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
{
    From = emailContent.From,
    To = emailContent.To,
    Cc = emailContent.Cc,
    Bcc = emailContent.Bcc,
    Subject = emailContent.Subject,
    Message = emailContent.Message
}).ToString());
queue.AddMessage(message);
```